# Joomla not loading css file

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates, css

Firefox is reporting:

> "The stylesheet was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/html" is not "text/css".

Chrome says:

> Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://xyz.com/".

The line which is causing the problem and marked :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/." type="text/css" />
```

I am using Joomla 3.5 and don't know how to resolve this issue...

this is the complete header created by joomla core / template:

```
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de-de" lang="de-de">

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var siteurl='/';
var tmplurl='/templates/ja_zite/';
var isRTL = false;
</script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;language=de-DE&amp;libraries=places'></script>
<script src="/templates/ja_zite/plugins/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/templates/ja_zite/plugins/jquery.masonry.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $JAM = jQuery.noConflict();

    $JAM(document).ready(function(){
        var JAMHelper = {
            sid: null,
            resize: function(){
                if($JAM('.itemListMasonry #itemListPrimary').length > 0){
                    $JAM('.itemListMasonry #itemListPrimary').masonry('reloadItems');
                }
            }
        };
        if($JAM('.itemListMasonry #itemListPrimary').length > 0){
            $JAM('.itemListMasonry #itemListPrimary').masonry({
                itemSelector: '.itemContainer',
                isResizable: true
            }); 
        }   
        $JAM(window).on('resize', function(){
            clearTimeout(JAMHelper.sid);
            JAMHelper.sid = setTimeout(JAMHelper.resize, navigator.userAgent.match(/Mobile/i) ? 500 : 250);
        });
    }); 
</script>
  <base href="http://kitchen2soul.com/index.php" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="kitchen2soul, seminare,stress,management,münchen,psychologie" />
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://kitchen2soul.com/index.php" />
  <meta property="og:title" content="Home" />
  <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
  <meta name="generator" content="Joomla! - Open Source Content Management" />
  <title>Home</title>
  <link href="/index.php" rel="canonical" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/index.php?jat3action=gzip&amp;jat3type=css&amp;jat3file=t3-assets%2Fcss_92d17.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/." type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/index.php?jat3action=gzip&amp;jat3type=css&amp;jat3file=t3-assets%2Fcss_0750d.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/index.php?jat3action=gzip&amp;jat3type=css&amp;jat3file=t3-assets%2Fcss_7d895.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/index.php?jat3action=gzip&amp;jat3type=css&amp;jat3file=t3-assets%2Fcss_c8a01.css" type="text/css" />
  <style type="text/css">
.title_green  {

color:#56AF75;
}
  </style>
  <script src="/index.php?jat3action=gzip&amp;jat3type=js&amp;jat3file=t3-assets%2Fjs_2be01.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/media/plugin_googlemap3/site/googlemaps/googlemapsv3.js'></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.hasTooltip').tooltip({"html": true,"container": "body"});
});
jQuery(function($) {
            SqueezeBox.initialize({});
            SqueezeBox.assign($('a.modal').get(), {
                parse: 'rel'
            });
        });
        function jModalClose() {
            SqueezeBox.close();
        }
jQuery(function($) {
             $('.hasTip').each(function() {
                var title = $(this).attr('title');
                if (title) {
                    var parts = title.split('::', 2);
                    var mtelement = document.id(this);
                    mtelement.store('tip:title', parts[0]);
                    mtelement.store('tip:text', parts[1]);
                }
            });
            var JTooltips = new Tips($('.hasTip').get(), {"maxTitleChars": 50,"fixed": false});
        });
  </script>

<!--[if ie]><link href="/plugins/system/jat3/jat3/base-themes/default/css/template-ie.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /><![endif]--> 
<!--[if ie 7]><link href="/plugins/system/jat3/jat3/base-themes/default/css/template-ie7.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /><![endif]--> 
<!--[if ie 7]><link href="/templates/ja_zite/css/template-ie7.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /><![endif]--> 
<!--[if ie 8]><link href="/templates/ja_zite/css/template-ie8.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /><![endif]--> 

<!-- META FOR IOS & HANDHELD -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
<meta name="apple-touch-fullscreen" content="YES" />
<!-- //META FOR IOS & HANDHELD -->


<link href="/plugins/system/jat3/jat3/base-themes/default/images/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300&amp;subset=cyrillic" />
<link href='/plugins/system/plugin_googlemap3/plugin_googlemap3.css.php' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />


<style type="text/css">
/*dynamic css*/
    body#bd,
    div.logo-text h1 a,
    div.ja-moduletable h3, div.moduletable h3,
    div.ja-module h3, div.module h3,
    h1.componentheading, .componentheading,
    .contentheading,
    .article-content h1,
    .article-content h2,
    .article-content h3,
    .article-content h4,
    .article-content h5,
    .article-content h6
    {font-family: 'Open Sans';font-weight:300;font-style:300;font-size:14px;
color:black;}
    div.logo-text h1, div.logo-text h1 a
    {font-family: 'Open Sans';font-weight:300;font-style:300;}
    #ja-splitmenu,
    #jasdl-mainnav,
    #ja-cssmenu li,
    #ja-megamenu ul.level0
    {font-family: 'Open Sans';font-weight:300;font-style:300;text-transform:uppercase;
color: #564E4E;}
    #ja-subnav,
    #jasdl-subnav,
    #ja-cssmenu li li,
    #ja-megamenu ul.level1
    {font-family: 'Open Sans';font-weight:300;font-style:300;}
    h1.componentheading, .componentheading
    {font-family: 'Open Sans';font-weight:300;font-style:300;}
    .contentheading,
    .article-content h1,
    .article-content h2,
    .article-content h3,
    .article-content h4,
    .article-content h5,
    .article-content h6
    {font-family: 'Open Sans';font-weight:300;font-style:300; }
    div.ja-moduletable h3, div.moduletable h3,
    div.ja-module h3, div.module h3
    {font-family: 'Open Sans';font-weight:300;font-style:300;}

    body.bd .main {width: 980px;}
    body.bd #ja-wrapper {min-width: 980px;}
</style></head>
```

Comment: Watching because I have the same error, but I think it's a different problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is a mistake in the template, even if you were using a generated CSS file it would have to be from a different address than the page currently being viewed.

```
/.
```

means, domain root there you have index.php file that generates all the content which is HTML and not CSS.

tl;dr. Remove this line, it doesn't do anything, and if you are missing some styling trey looking for it in

```
/templates/ja_zite/
```